# Назывное предложение или именительный темы?

Tags: синтаксис, именительный-темы

Новые учебники по русскому языку "радуют" лингвистическими открытиями. Всегда считала, что именительный темы - это фигура речи, а назывное предложение - грамматическая характеристика односоставного предложения. И одно другому не мешает: по структуре предложение назывное, а с точки зрения стилистической  - может быть и именительным темы.  С удивлением прочитала  в учебнике 9 класса рассуждение о том, как отличить назывное предложение от именительного темы. Для меня это нечто вроде "как отличить эпитет от определения" А что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: А мой-то еще в 6-ом. Боже, что нам еще предстоит (((

Comment: Я все-таки надеюсь, что данный случай - изыск запутавшихся в терминологии новаторов.  
Хотя частенько действительно не по себе иногда становится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хочется комментировать, не прочитав упомянутое рассуждение.

Что до меня, именительный темы - это это функция именительного падежа (как, скажем, родительный сравнения или творительный субъекта), а назывное предложение - структура, где эта функция реализуется.

Т.е. с одной стороны, "именительный темы" - понятие все-таки грамматическое (помимо, разумеется стилистики), с другой - они с назывным предложениям действительно в разных "плоскостях" находятся. Т.е. мне ближе аналогия "как отличить часть речи от члена предложения".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в учебниках, о которых Вы говорите,  отражены разные позиции лингвистов относительно таких предложений. Вот цитата из работы об именительном темы.

"Н.С. Валгина (1971) не считает именительный темы / именительный представления предложением, так как, по её мнению, несмотря на интонационную завершённость, именительный темы / представления не заключает в себе значения бытия и не способен к самостоятельному функционированию".  (http://www.referun.com/n/imenitelnyy-temy-kak-osobaya-raznovidnost-nominativnyh-predlozheniy)
  Приводятся точки зрения и других учёных-лингвистов.  В общем, спорят. Поэтому, пока не ввели единые программы и учебники на всей территории России, мы будем иногда открывать для себя что-то новое, ибо авторы учебников далеко не всегда одинаково смотрят на ту или иную проблему.

Ларf, программа по русскому языку Граник в 7 классе односоставные назывные предложения рассматривает как двусоставные номинативные. Правда, авторы учебника нашли ход: они приводят и другую точку зрения на такие предложения и советуют детям озвучивать обе, если им придётся о таких предложениях говорить.

Comment: Вы по ГРанику занимаетесь? Я из его учебников только 9 класс видела, остальное только в отрывках в газете "Русский язык". Мне нравится. Он очень умело сочетает научность и популярность, хороший психолог. Но у нас, с одной стороны, у учителя есть выбор, с другой - очень настойчиво рекомендуют определенных авторов. Занимаемся по Львову.

Comment: Именительный темы как разновидность номинативных предложений только изучается, а значит, рано еще включать в школьный курс. Или нужно выделять в особый раздел такие темы для школьных научных конференций, что ли, для тех, кто интересуется языком. Но не для всех. Каша у них в головах получается. А для экзамена отбирают однозначный материал. Где гарантия, что ребенок не запутается, как это бывает в ЕГЭ с причастием и деепричастием. В заданиях на часть речи мы считаем их отдельным разрядом, а в вопросе по словообразованию - суффиксы причастий и деепричастий считаются формообразующими.

Comment: Совершенно согласна с Вами! Да, я уже третий год иду по Граник (это женщина, зовут её Генриетта Григорьевна), мне очень нравится. Единственное, что вызвало недоумение, - фонема введена в 5(!)классе, а с ней и понятие фонемных и нефонемных правил... Фонетический разбор чуть ли не на уровне университета с 5 класса, со всеми редуцированными. Это, наверное, лишне.   
Зато сложносочинённые и сложноподчиненные предложения с 5 класса- это здорово!

Comment: Спасибо за информацию . А что пропустили мой вопрос про сочинение на ГИА (про абзацное членение)? Видно, девятого класса у Вас нет...

Comment: Сейчас же найду вопрос про сочинение. 9 класса в этом году у меня нет, есть 5 (л), 6, 7 (р), 11(л). Лара, Мне часто хочется познакомиться с Вами ближе, тем более что мы ровесницы и у нас одинаковое отношение к русскому языку. Если Вы зарегистрированы "В контакте" , заходите ко мне (http://vk.com/id46931854) и добавляйтесь в друзья, буду рада.

Comment: Ссылка не открывается, почему-то. Я не зарегистрирована там, но попробую Вас разыскать.... Нашла!!!

Comment: Ура!!! Спасибо!